# How to format hAxis label date in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I saw [this documentation on Google Developer site](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes), they show me how to format 
hAxis label but only label with number format. I don't know how to format the labels that use date format. Here is my chart:
[image]

I want to format the date from `Dec 7, 2015` to `7 Dec`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'd MMM',
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/9t6daLkq)

See documentation here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#formatting-axis-gridline-and-tick-labels